# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class invariant violation when using Glassfish

Tags: jsf, illegalstateexception

I have some trouble with re-deployment.
First deployment, its ok. But then it throws this exception. I have to restart GlassFish. Why is it necessary?

```
SEVERE: log4j:ERROR log4j called after unloading, see http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#unload.
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class invariant violation
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLoggerRepository(LogManager.java:199)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:228)
at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:64)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:253)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:645)
at com.icesoft.faces.component.portlet.Portlet.<clinit>(Portlet.java:38)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:140)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:949)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:930)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:680)
at 
...

SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'bundle://184.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have another parser like `xerces.jar` in your app which is trying to override default parser of glassfish but is unable to do so during redeployment.

If you have any parser implementation jar then make it a default parser by adding

`-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/myapp/lib/xerces.jar` to your server startup.

http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/cannot-deploy-application-includes-xerces-jar-glassfish-311

Comment: Thank you. But I don't know, how to do it - should I edit some configuration file of GlassFish or is it possible to write this instruction to some dialog of IDE (I use NetBeans).

Comment: have a look into this , http://www.gerardsetho.net/2011/02/add-jvm-options-to-glassfish.html

Comment: I have done this, but I have got the same error -       <java-config debug-options="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009" system-classpath="" classpath-suffix="">
 
        <jvm-options>-Djava.endorsed.dirs=${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/modules/endorsed${path.separator}${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/endorsed</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/myapp/lib/xerces.jar</jvm-options>
        
        ...
      </java-config>

Comment: why did u keep '/myapp/lib/xerces.jar' ?Is your app name myapp ? That was just the name I used , do you have xerces.jar in your application library(lib folder) ? If so give the path of that in place of '/myapp/lib/xerces.jar'